# My Userdefault is not saving data and its not being mapped by ObjectMapper in swift

Tags: swift, objectmapper, userdefaults

I want a customer to sign up and after entering the data its mapped to a user default and saved there and when i want to verify the user i call a function Verify that gets the data that is saved from the user to verify the user yet the mapping of data in GET is not working

```
var UserInfoDefualts: UserModel {
    set {
        let userJson = try! JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
        let jsonString = String(data: userJson, encoding: .utf8)!
        KeychainWrapper.standard.set(jsonString, forKey: "UserData")
    }
    get {
        let userJosn = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "UserData") ?? ""

        let userData = Mapper<UserModel>().map(JSONString: userJosn) ?? UserModel()
        return userData
    }
}
```

The get is not mapping the data userdata is always NIL, where in teh set its Filled properly

The SignUp Function

```
@IBAction func continueButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
ApiServices.shared.signUp(name: fullName.text!, number: phoneNumber.text!, gender: 1, date: birthDate.text!) { (result, statusCode) in
    print(result)
    if statusCode == 200 {
        let userData = result
        print(userData.fullName)
        UserInfoDefualts = userData
        ScreenLoader().pushVC(rootView: self, viewController: Verify_VC)
           // Shared.logIn(userData: userData)

    }
}
```

}

The verify function

```
    @IBAction func verifyClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        var data = UserInfoDefualts
        ApiServices.shared.verifyUser(userID: UserInfoDefualts.userId ?? 0, otpCode: self.code) { (result, statusCode) in
            if statusCode == 200 {
                ScreenLoader().pushVC(rootView: self, viewController: Welcome_VC)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Once again forget outdated `ObjectMapper` and decode the data with `Decodable`.

Comment: @vadian can you please show me how, i already added the Decodable to my Struct USERMODEL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the structs replace `Encodable` with `Codable` and remove all code related to `ObjectMapper`

Then replace the computed property with

```
var userInfoDefaults: UserModel? {
    set {
        let userJson = try! JSONEncoder().encode(newValue!)
        let jsonString = String(data: userJson, encoding: .utf8)!
        KeychainWrapper.standard.set(jsonString, forKey: "UserData")
    }
    get {
        guard let userJosn = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "UserData") else { return nil }

        let data = Data(userJosn.utf8)
        do {
          return try JSONDecoder().decode(UserModel.self, from: data)
        } catch {
          print(error)
          return nil
        }
    }
}
```

As `UserModel` has no custom initializer the computed property must be an optional. So you have to write in the IBAction

```
guard let data = userInfoDefaults else { return }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store objectmapper object in userdefault like below:

```
if let userInfo = Mapper<SignInModel>().map(JSONObject: dictionary["signup"]) {
if let JSONString = Mapper().toJSONString(userInfo, prettyPrint: true) {

//User Info:-
let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: JSONString)
UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "userinfo")

}
```